# How can I align two flex boxes to follow each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a menu, and I'd like the div.right-controls (and in theory also div.left-controls) to align with `.navbar-start` (which contains the X amount of menu items). See:

[image]

I have tried with justify-content: `flex-start`, and it works:

[image]

but if I make the window bigger or smaller, it's no longer aligned:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a container element (something that will hold both your controls and menu underneath at a certain width and centered).
Here is a example CSS (tweak it to your needs):

```
.container {
width: 80%;
max-width: 1250px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was the way to go!